# How to make auto test working with already login part

Tags: javascript, php, selenium-webdriver, codeception

First of all i'm first time working with automatic tests, so sorry if my question will be easy or difficult in description of my problem.

I'm working with Selenium2 and Codeception for creating and using auto test.
For example i have a test which include few parts:

1. Login as a member
2. Searching information
3. Working with results

Parts 2 and 3  can not be done without 1. So every test writing starting with Login part and to be honest i don't like this because it makes longer test time and more code. So here  is my question. How to make to past 1 part. It's possible? I want that this test already start and you will be already logged.

---

Here is my code of first part:

```
$I = new WebGuy($scenario);
$I->amOnPage('/authorization__auth_client');
$I->wait(1000);
$I->fillField('login', 'autotest');
$I->fillField('pass','autotest');
$I->click('go');
```

And this is second for example:

```
$I->click('.js-datepicker');
$I->fillField('.js-datepicker','06.11.2013');
$I->fillField('.js-autocomplete-dep-0','KBP');
$I->wait(4000);
$I->fillField('.js-autocomplete-arr-0','MOW');
$I->wait(4000);
$I->click('gogo');
$I->wait(15000);
$I->seeElement('.pro-btn');
$I->click('.pro-user-info_reg');
```

So, how to solved my problem. It would be grate, if you show on my examples if it's possible of course.

Answer (score 0):

To 'skip' the login part add cookies. I'm not familiar with Codeception, but google brought me [here](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Selenium2).
And here's the cookies setting part

```
setCookie

Sets a cookie.

param $cookie
param $value
return mixed
```

All you need is to get the right cookie to set